# Remove empty lines after Ctrl+K Ctrl+D

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In VS 2012 and earlier i was able to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which would change

```
<div>

   <div>

      <asp:TextBox runat="server" Id="Textbox1"></asp:/TextBox>

   </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
   <div>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" Id="Textbox1"></asp:/TextBox>
   </div>
</div>
```

So it would remove the extra lines. In `VS 2013` when i do the same it doesn't format it correctly (or in the way i prefer).

I've looked under **Tools** but nothing that i can see that would sort the issue, i also have **Productivity Power Tools** installed and again no option to remove the extra lines.

Anyway around this?

**Edit 1**

using \n\n and \n
[image: Search]

Comment: For a workaround replace \n\n with \n

Comment: I hit Ctrl-H enter \n\n and  \n in the bottom box = "The following specified text was not found:  \n\n"

Comment: For \n to be interpreted as newline you must enable regular expressions in search box.

Comment: Just make sure to disable it afterwards, because it may confuse you in some future search.

Comment: Strange i think im doing this correctly but nothing happens (See Edit 1 in my original post of what im doing)

Comment: The icon that looks like dot and asterisk (.*) is the one I'm talking about. Also, not sure if it matters in this search, but might want to disable the neighbor option (match whole word).

Comment: is there any solution

Comment: No solution that im aware of

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, line endings are `\r\n`.  To search for blank lines, search for `^\r\n` with regular expressions on and replace with a blank string.

[image]

Note: the `Replace...` shown is an empty string placeholder.